# Cordova/Phonegap - Where do I put a data file I want to read?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been driving myself crazy trying to find the answer to a seemingly easy question.

I am trying to create my first app using Cordova. I want to bundle a text file with my app that can be read when the app starts up.

Where do I put this file?

`dataDirectory` seems like a good place, but where is it? [Documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout) says `/data/data/<app-id>/files` but where are those `data` directories? Do I create them?

Update 1: Ok, I think I've figured out that `dataDirectory` should be pretty much just where the path says it should be, at the root of the file system. But the directory doesn't appear to be created automatically and I don't know how to package a file - a JSON file, for instance - and place it in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you do not need to create these directories. Those are created once your app is installed by the Android itself.

A typical way to get this done would be that you could first off add those files in your app's assets directory and then at runtime you can copy those file wherever you want.

There is a [repository on Githup](https://github.com/gkcgautam/Asset2SD) which provide a similar functionality.